# Bulma column didn't work (doesn't show) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, bulma

I used laravel and I download bulma package from bulma site. I extract this file on public folder. This css like navbar, container, works normally. But after I try to create a column, this column does not show up. I add this src in my head like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="{{ asset('theme/bulma-0.8.2/bulma-0.8.2/css/bulma.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('theme/bulma-0.8.2/bulma-0.8.2/css/bulma.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

but I create a column like this :

```
 <div class="columns">
     <div class="column">
        First column
         </div>
     <div class="column">
        Second column
         </div>
     <div class="column">
        Third column
       </div>
     <div class="column">
        Fourth column
     </div>
 </div>
```

like this picture [picture](https://ibb.co/N9PsgMb)

What is wrong about this?

Comment: is your CSS location correct? Do you get a 404 in your browser? As well why are you loading twice the same CSS (min and normal)?

Comment: What is the problem? I can't see anything irregular in the screenshot...